# Open a HTML application (HTA) in background with Batch File

Tags: html, batch-file, process, hta, pastebin

Well, I have this code on my Batch File:

```
@echo off
echo Espere...
start /MIN /WAIT Registro.hta
echo Terminado!
pause
```

But it doesn't work, it so strange...

And my Registro.hta's code: http://pastebin.com/4qzwL4RC

I don't know what I'm doing bad? Can you explain me why Registro.hta is opening on foreground and not in background?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an HTA to start minimized, you have to set its [`WINDOWSTATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to `minimize`.

Comment: That might be due to the `&done=http://google.es` in the URL you load in the `<object>` tag.

Comment: Ok, I will delete this line anyway. :P Thanks :)